# Error formatting volume read only volume

Tags: partitioning, mount, usb-drive, disk, read-only

When right click on usb and select format from menu I get this error below.

```
Error wiping device: Command-line `wipefs -a "/dev/sdc1"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: wipefs: error: /dev/sdc1: probing initialization failed: Read-only file system
 (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

Here is a picture of it:

[image: Error formatting volume]

Also I've checked "disks" application shows it as read only mount

[image: read only mount]

Also checked other operating systems, none of could format it.

Answer (score 0):

The hardware was corrupted by some reasons which I could not understand.
If you try all things written up and can not get any result, can be sure the usb drive will not be used anymore.